# Speed up Workbooks.Open in background

Tags: vba, excel

This code works well for me, the only problem is, the workbook that I am opening is a rather large file, and it takes a prolonged period of time to open, slowing down the startup of my program.  Is there any way to speed this up?  The file I am opening only gets filtered and read, nothing is written in the program, and doesn't need to be saved.  Any suggestions?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open("\Item Setup\MODIFIED ITEM EXTRACT.xlsm")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

PriceVerifier.Show
```

Comment: *a rather large file* - large file take a large amount of time to open. You can open as `Read Only` (doubt it will help) and also play with `updating links on opening` argument, if that is a factor. you could also write a program in that workbook that updates a flat file with the information you need whenever it gets updated and call that smaller flat file in this program ... not sure if that is feasible, but just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to do with the workbook, but if this would help I can write a better answer. When I had a similar problem I ended up using a query to extract the data without opening the workbook, and then putting it into a pivot table in the already open workbook. The data gets extracted almost instantly.

Comment: You can try setting calculation to manual whilst the file is opening with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: Per @jcarroll you'll be better off using one of several methods to extract the data from the workbook **without** opening the file. There are plenty of examples of how to do that here on SO.

Comment: If you only need a couple of different ranges from the file, you could try using a ADORecordset to copy those ranges to the current workbook.

Comment: You should also disable Auto_Open macros to run, with `Application.EnableEvents = False`, in case you do have such autorun macros in the file to open.

Comment: @jcarroll thanks for your response.  Your solution sounds like the best for my situation, and ti sounds like you were in a similar situation.  I have roughly 290,000 rows of items with 5 columns worth of data.  What my program does is it filters the first column by a price standard number, then from that selection I use the PercentRank property to show the percentile a given weight is within that price standard number.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your own path in DBPath, your own fields in Test Field, and your own worksheet in Manual Entry. Leave the $ though.

```
Sub sbADOExample()

    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim DBPath As String
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    DBPath = "C:\user\testFile.xlsx"

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=" & """" & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES" & """;"

    strSQL = "SELECT [Test Field] FROM [Manual Entry$] "

    rst.Open strSQL, strConn

    Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close

End Sub
```